# What are the ways to compress Video without using FFMPEG in Android

Tags: android, video-compression

I need to compress video and upload it to the Server.I do not want to use FFMPEG. I referred many links but solutions are given using FFMPEG. Please Suggest Ideas to compress video WITHOUT using FFMPEG. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this Library.its easy way to get compress better video . https://github.com/Tourenathan-G5organisation/SiliCompressor